# split different part in sentence using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have 1,000,000 PDF files from which I want to scrape data  and build a database. Scraping them produced some data like:

```
 Mobile: 98-912-7990154Home: 98-21-44157129ppouriya@yahoo.comUnit 12 - No. 15 - West 19th Alley - South Varzi St. -West Ferdows Blvd. - Sadeghiyeh Sq.1483676479,Tehran
```

How can i split them and have data like:

```
Mobile: 98-912-7990154
Home: 98-21-44157129
Email: ppouriya@yahoo.com
Address : Unit 12 - No. 15 - West 19th Alley - South Varzi St. -West Ferdows Blvd. - Sadeghiyeh Sq.1483676479,Tehran
```

Comment: what have you tried to do? is there a space/line break between `ppouriya@yahoo.comUnit`?

Comment: Are the fields always in the same order? What do they look like if there is no value in them? (For example, a person with no Home number, or no email)

Comment: Will it always be these 4 fields, or are there more?

Comment: I've edited to clean up the grammar. If I've changed what you meant, please feel free to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42516169/edit) to fix things or even rollback my changes. That said, it will help folks help you if you show the code you have written.

Comment: no some of them has no email or phone number

Comment: what does the input look like with no email and/or phone number?

Comment: Mobile: 98-912-7990154Home: 98-21-44157129Unit 12 - No. 15 - West 19th Alley - South Varzi St. -West Ferdows Blvd. - Sadeghiyeh Sq.1483676479,Tehran

Answer (score 1):

So you have a "mark" for split lines, such as `Home`, `Email`, `Address`.

if you are using regex, you can find the location of word.

`[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pattern, string)]`

example:

```
import re

data = 'Mobile: 98-912-7990154Home: 98-21-44157129ppouriya@yahoo.comUnit 12 - No. 15 - West 19th Alley - South Varzi St. -West Ferdows Blvd. - Sadeghiyeh Sq.1483676479,Tehran'
p = re.search("Home", data)
```

then this will return the location of word `Home`. start location is `p[0]` so you can split the `data` with this information as well.

Comment: some of them has no mail or mobile number

Comment: That shouldn't matter @OmidGoudazi since you can just return the index of the keywords that exist.

Comment: attention to this part: Home: 98-21-44157129ppouriya@yahoo.comUnit 12 - No. 15 - West 19th Alley - South Varzi St. -West Ferdows Blvd. - Sadeghiyeh Sq.1483676479,Tehran

Comment: there is no pattern to separate them